# Cross Domain webservice calling in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, web-services, jquery-mobile, jsonp, getjson

I am calling webservice using below method.

**// This is flicker API and it is working fine.**

```
//var url="http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?";
```

**// This is my created webservie and it is not working**

```
var url="http://windowsdemo.projectstatus.co.uk/B60/B60Services.asmx/getBanners?jsoncallback=?";
```

This is method

```
        $.getJSON(url,
        function(data){
          alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        });
```

If I use my created webservice then it show this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` And flickr api is returning data properly.

While both are returning data if I put in browser. What may be the issue.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Use `crossdomain.xml` in your base directory.

Comment: How to use crossdomain.xml

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to parse an invalid JSON response, thus the `Unexpected token :` error.

Put it through **[jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/)** and try to correct the anomalies.

Comment: I validate the response and found it valid.